# WPF web application contextmenu on left click

Tags: c#, wpf, web, uwp-xaml, xbap

I got a very strange problem. I want to open a contextmenu on left click on a button... Here is my solution but it fires an System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception.

```
public class ButtonKontext : System.Windows.Controls.Button
{
    public ButtonKontext()
    {
        this.Click += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(this.Button_Click_1);

    }

    public void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ContextMenu != null)
        {
            //ContextMenu contextMenu = this.ContextMenu;
            //this.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = this;
            this.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;  // System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception here
        }
    }
}
```

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: "Untergeordnetes Fenster kann nicht auf der obersten Ebene erstellt werden"
--> edit: Child window can not be created at the top level – Thx Jimenemex for correct translation.

The thing is, if i right click the button the contextmenu shows up normal. So what is the problem here? Any idea?

Comment: At the normal wpf (.exe) the problem does not exsist only on wpf (xbap).

Comment: `Untergeordnetes Fenster kann nicht auf der obersten Ebene erstellt werden` = `Child window can not be created at the top level`

Comment: BTW, after Microsoft introduced XBAP, the internet itself switched to HTML5 and there is no longer a need to inject WPF or Silverlight into web browsers. Right now Microsoft is doing the Blazor experiment, https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor